# UITableView same frame regardless of orientation

Tags: ios, uikit

In the debugger, I get the following output regardless of the orientation...

```
print self.tableView.frame

(CGRect) $R2 = (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 1000, height = 1000))
```

Why doesn't the size change depending on the orientation?

Comment: The tableview has same width and height, doesn't it?

Comment: When are you printing the value?  If you are printing it before the view is layed out then the subviews won't have their final frames.

Comment: @dan oh that's more like it. Now I get 568 vs 320. Thanks. Where is it getting 1000 from?

Comment: @Hoa My table's dimensions are not hard coded to be equal - the edges are pinned to the edges of the view controller.